# How do I write a decoder to map a list of values for a custom data type?

Tags: elm

I'm struggling to write a decoder for a list of links:

```
listOfLinksDecoder : Decoder (List JsonLink)
listOfLinksDecoder =
    Decode.map (List JsonLink)
        (field "Links" <| Decode.list linkDecoder)
```

> Error:
>
> ```
> Decode.map (List JsonLink)
> ```
>
> Cannot find variable `List`

Please note that I have been successful in writing a decoder for a single link:

```
linkDecoder : Decoder JsonLink
linkDecoder =
    Decode.map6 JsonLink
        (field "Profile" profileDecoder)
        (field "Title" Decode.string)
        (field "Url" Decode.string)
        (field "ContentType" Decode.string)
        (field "Topics" <| Decode.list topicDecoder)
        (field "IsFeatured" Decode.bool)
```

Please note that I attempted to search [this documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode). However, I was still unable to find an example for my case.

**Appendix:**

```
topicLinks : Id -> Topic -> ContentType -> (Result Http.Error (List JsonLink) -> msg) -> Cmd msg
topicLinks providerId topic contentType msg =
    let
        url =
            baseUrl ++ (getId providerId) ++ "/" ++ "topiclinks"

        body =
            encodeId providerId |> Http.jsonBody

        request =
            Http.post url body linksDecoder
    in
        Http.send msg request
```

Comment: Why not just `listOfLinksDecoder = Decode.list linkDecoder` ? I think that should be the correct type. The first argument to `Decode.map` should be a function, but `List JsonLink` is a type.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to map, you can just do:

```
listOfLinksDecoder : Decoder (List JsonLink)
listOfLinksDecoder =
    field "Links" <| Decode.list linkDecoder
```

Also note that `Cannot find variable List` error is because `List` is a type and not a constructor/function.